# Why is variable that get_post_meta stored in empty?

Tags: post-meta

I have used the following bit of code in another script on the same site, & it worked there.

```
$this_post_id = get_the_ID();
$key_2_value =  get_post_meta( $this_post_id, 'custom_select', true );
if( ! empty( $key_2_value )) {
echo $key_2_value ;
 ;}
var_dump($key_2_value)
```

`var_dump` outputs  `string '' (length=0)`

I am trying to use it in a script called events-list.php. Events-list.php provides a short list of the events (which are posts) .

The meta field is definitely called `custom_select`

Comment: Is get_the_ID returning anything? Echo it out and make sure there's actually an ID.

Comment: You have two semicolons inside your `if` statement. Aside from that: What does `get_the_ID()` return and in what context are you calling that? Please add answers with an [edit] to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable that `get_post_meta` was stored in was empty because I wasn't getting an `id`. I was trying to use this code on a category page, not a single event. Without an `id` it couldn't identify the `post_meta` to use. So  I corrected it with the following:

```
$latest_cpt = get_posts("post_type=event&numberposts=1"); 
    $theidone =$latest_cpt[0]->ID;

    $this_post_id =  $theidone; //get_the_ID();
    $key_2_value =  get_post_meta( $this_post_id, 'custom_select', true );
    if( ! empty( $key_2_value )) {
    $thisisworking =   $key_2_value ;
```